# Code to tap anywhere on screen to take photo

Tags: android, cordova, camera, screen

Does anyone know how I could code for a camera function that to take the picture the user just has to tap anywhere on the screen?  I am writing the app with Phonegap in Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute the navigator.camera.getPicture() method you are firing off the Intent to start the Android Camera. The Camera provides the UI to take the picture so you'll need to use their shutter button.

If you want to do the click anywhere functionality you'll need to write a plugin to provide your own camera functionality.

Comment: besides just the main http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins any good ways to learn how to do that?

Comment: That is probably the best way to start learning to develop plugins.